# Reading a 16-bit timer on an 8-bit MCU

Tags: microcontroller, timer, pic

Since an 8-bit MCU can't read the whole 16-bit timer in one cycle, this creates a race condition where the low-word can roll over between reads.  Does the community have a preferred method of avoiding these race conditions?  I'm currently considering stopping the timer during reads, but I'd like to know if there's a more elegant solution.

FYI, this is for a [PIC16F690](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41262E.pdf).

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162673/how-to-read-two-32bit-counters-as-a-64bit-integer-without-race-condition

Comment: This is a problem all microcontrollers take care of, AFAIK. When one byte is read, the other one is latched, and reading the other byte will read from the latch. Problem solved.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Windell's right, if you're talking about PICs, the datasheet (and hardware) already handle this for you.

If you're not using a PIC, the general method I use is to do this:

```
byte hi, lo;
word timer_value;

do {
    hi = TIMER_HI;
    lo = TIMER_LO;
} while(hi != TIMER_HI);

timer_value = (hi << 8) | lo;
```

What this does is to read the upper byte followed by the lower byte, and to continue doing so until the hi byte doesn't change.  This readily handles the case where the low byte of the 16-bit value overflows between reads.  It assumes, of course, that there are no side effects from reading the TIMER_HI register multiple times. If your particular microprocessor doesn't allow that, it's time to throw it out and use one that isn't quite as braindead. :-)

This method ALSO assumes that your timer isn't changing so rapidly that you run the risk of overflowing the low 8 bits within a processor fetch cycle or two.  If you're running a timer so fast (or a microprocessor so slow) then it's time to re-think your implementation.

Comment: You can also use this technique to read a timer made up of a hardware timer and a software counter incremented in the overflow interrupt.

Comment: Thanks, I actually like this technique better than stuttering the timer during a read.

Comment: Finally found a Microchip app note, "PIC Micro Mid-range MCU family".  It looks to be old, but seems to describe the 16F series in greater detail than the datasheet.  The technique suggested for reading the 16-bit free-running timer matches quite well with your suggestion, so I'm marking it as the answer.

Comment: In general, my answer would have been "do what the compiler does" - write something in C, and see and see what the assembly looks like.

Comment: O_Engenheiro The loop executes twice for the case where an overflow occurs, and once in all other circumstances.  If you are looping more than that then either your timer clock is WAY too fast or your CPU is WAY too slow.

Comment: @Andrew Kohlsmith, I deleted my comment. Sorry, I made an incorrect analysis of the code. Thanks.

Comment: @Andrew Kohlsmith: If the timer is in synchronous mode, your approach is fine.  If the timer is running in asynchronous mode and isn't too fast (e.g. it's running off a 32KHz watch crystal) it's better to reloop if the LSB of the timer has changed.  Otherwise there's a risk that the timer might change precisely as it's being read, yielding an invalid reading.

Comment: @supercat I am not sure I understand; if the timer is asynchronous to the CPU clock then you will be at most 1 timer tick off; that doesn't mean the reading is invalid. If, however, you mean that the bit pattern in the register will be invalid then it's a very poor CPU/peripheral design; peripheral registers should be properly synchronized by the vendor.

Comment: @Andrew Kohlsmith: A counter which may be reliably read by a CPU whose clock is asynchronous to it requires a fair bit of silicon.  Essentially, one must either count in graycode or convert the count to graycode, then synchronize that, and then convert the graycode value back to "normal" binary.  For cases where the CPU clock will--*when running*--be at least 3x faster than the signal to be counted, it might be easier to arrange for the counter to be clocked synchronously when the CPU is awake and asynchronously when it's asleep...

Comment: @Andrew Kohlsmith: ...but switching between synchronous and asynchronous clocking without gaining or losing a count--even in edge cases--is difficult.  If software can get by with reading the timer repeatedly until it gets the same answer multiple times, that will be allow the use of simpler hardware than would otherwise be necessary.  Note that the only time that approach really won't work is when the count rate is pretty high compared with the to the CPU clock rate, which would suggest that the graycode approach is the right one.

Comment: @Andrew Kohlsmith: Note that unless a facility is provided for synchronous 16-bit reading, or the count rate is so fast that the CPU won't be able to read low-high-low before low changes, there's no real disadvantage to having the counter return corrupt values if it's read while it's changing (it's certainly less of a disadvantage than would be an occasional gained or lost count caused by switching between synchronous and asynchronous modes).

Comment: @supercat interesting. I've dealt with a lot of microcontrollers over the years and am learning VHDL and I've never run across this before. I also conferred with my VHDL "tutor" and he's also never seen this kind of problem in a microcontroller. Where have you seen this before? I bet that was a real bear to debug!

Comment: @Andrew Kohlsmith: Debugging async stuff isn't too hard if one assumes signals will go out of their way to change at the worst possible times.  Actually, in many cases I prefer totally unsynchronized timers to those which attempt to avoid the problems associated with being asynchronous, since I have on a number of occasions had to deal with hardware bugs related to such matters.  For example, one undocumented annoyance on many PIC timers is that if the timer holds a value other than FFFF, and it's written with FFFF, the overflow interrupt...

Comment: ...won't happen on the next count, but instead after 65,537 counts.  I suspect that design stems from a desire to avoid having a spurious interrupt get triggered if e.g. the counter had held 128 and it was being written with 127 just as a count came in, but I would have rather simply had the documentation specify that any write to the timer in async mode may erroneously set the interrupt flag, so safe operation would require disabling the interrupt, writing the timer, clearing the flag, and re-enabling the interrupt.

Comment: @Andrew Kohlsmith: What I'd most like to have would be a system with an asynchronous 48-bit counter, running from its own supply, and a compare register on the bottom 32 bits which could operate even when the processor's main clock was stopped.  There would be no need to write to the 48-bit counter, and I wouldn't mind having to disable compare interrupts when writing to the compare register.  A timer system like that would allow an RTOS to schedule tasks with 17us or 33us precision, and power down the main oscillator any time it wasn't needed.

Comment: @Andrew Kohlsmith: The EFM Gekko is almost perfect; my only complaint is that the timer is only 24 bits and can't keep time while the CPU is powered down.  The ST Micro 32F series seems somewhat better, with a real-time clock in the form of a 32-bit linear counter and programmable prescalar.  My only complaint with that 32 bits is a little too short (using a 256Hz count rate, the thing would effectively forget the date if powered down for a year; at a faster count rate it would overflow sooner).

Comment: @Andrew Kohlsmith: Unfortunately, ST somewhat ruined things with the 32L series.  The RTC chip has a settable prescalar, but unfortunately has to be read out in a YMDHMS format which assumes a 1-second increment rate, and its alarm registers assume HMS format; if the count rate is 256Hz, the alarm registers would represent units of 1/256 second, 15/64 second, and 14 1/16 second (with the latter wrapping every 337.5 seconds).  Far less convenient for use with RTOS scheduling.

Answer (score 10):

Check your datasheet!  It *will* talk about this, in gory detail, for your particular chip.

I'm not certain that this is true for all 16-bit counter/timer registers on all PICs (maybe someone else can answer that!) but at least for the PIC 18F that I use, the datasheet specifically talks about how this is handled.

When you read the low byte, it buffers the high byte into a temporary register for the high byte, so that when you read the high byte next, it gives you a full instantaneous snapshot of the timer value.

The same basic process is used on AVR (and Arduino of course), and for most other cases where you need to read or write two-byte registers at once on 8-bit MCUs.

Comment: i too recall reading this in AVR docs

Comment: Of course I checked the datasheet, but it's actually not as gory as you might think.  Nothing in the text for timer1 (chapter 6) indicates that the high byte gets buffered.  The there's a subsection under the async counter (6.5.1) that says "for writes, it is recommended that the user simply stop the timer and write the desired values".  Nothing is mentioned for reads.  That's why I came to the community

Comment: It *does* make it much easier now that you've posted the actual chip that you're using.  ;)

And... I'd call it pretty gory: it explicitly says that overflow can occur between the reads. Your solution, stopping the timer, is indeed inelegant but perhaps a *safe* one, depending on your application.

Answer (score 3):

The text you referred to in your comment (Section 6.5.1) refers to asynchronous timer operation, where the timer is clocked from a source external to the microcontroller.

The disclaimer is suggesting starting and stopping the timer because Andrew's general method (really any method) won't work because there may be many ticks (More than 256, even) of the external clock and thus the timer in a single cycle of the processor.  I assume you're not running with this edge case.

If, instead, you're using the internal oscillator as a reference, you'll be fine.  Even with a prescaler of 1, you've got up to 255 cycles after you read the high byte to read the low byte.  This should be a 2 cycle operation.  You still need the do/while loop in case your high byte changes (What is the difference between 'hi' and 'TIMER_HI' if the value of 'lo' is 0?) between these times.  With a prescaler of 2 or greater, you don't need this test anymore.  It's only with prescalers much less than 1 that it starts to become a problem, and this is impossible without the external clock.

Comment: Yeah, I know it was async timer, but it's the closest the datasheet got to addressing the problem.  Although now it makes more sense why they would suggest stopping the clock as opposed to mentioning Andrew's solution (even though they don't even mention *that* in the datasheet, but some separate app-note)

Answer (score 2):

There is an example in the [PIC Mid-Range MCU Family Reference Manual](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/33023a.pdf) for Reading and Writing Timer1 in Asynchronous Counter Mode.

Example: Reading a 16-bit Free-Running Timer

```
; All interrupts are disabled
MOVF TMR1H, W ; Read high byte
MOVWF TMPH ;
MOVF TMR1L, W ; Read low byte
MOVWF TMPL ;
MOVF TMR1H, W ; Read high byte
SUBWF TMPH, W ; Sub 1st read with 2nd read
BTFSC STATUS,Z ; Is result = 0
GOTO CONTINUE ; Good 16-bit read
;
; TMR1L may have rolled over between the read of the high and low bytes.
; Reading the high and low bytes now will read a good value.
;
MOVF TMR1H, W ; Read high byte
MOVWF TMPH ;
MOVF TMR1L, W ; Read low byte
MOVWF TMPL ;
; Re-enable the Interrupt (if required)
CONTINUE ; Continue with your code
```

Comment: Yup, that's the manual which confirmed that Andrew's template was the best compromise.  Although I modified his example to look more like the assembly; i.e. instead of do-while, I just used an if.